# YouTube URL parser chokes on underscore and dash

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, videos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fail of markdown parser detected if _ are used in naked url](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100882/fail-of-markdown-parser-detected-if-are-used-in-naked-url)
>   [Link with double-underscored word in URL renders incorrectly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117230/link-with-double-underscored-word-in-url-renders-incorrectly)

I'm posting [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-G520ACFUo) as part of the solution to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/45239/9300), but the problem is that the YouTube URL parser chokes on the link.

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-G520ACFUo
```

The URL has both a dash and underscore in it and that seems to break the parser.

```
http://youtu.be/_-G520ACFUo
```

The short version does not work either.

Comment: I have performed wizardry; URL-encoding the underscore as `%5f` seems to be a workaround. For reference, [here's the answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45239/2d-platformer-similar-to-sonic/45280#45280), and [here's the last borked revision](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/45280/2). Oh, and that particular video has embedding disabled, anyway.

Comment: Ah, this is actually another form of [this issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117230/link-with-double-underscored-word-in-url-renders-incorrectly).

Comment: happened to me on http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50522/how-should-i-record-high-quality-video-game-footage