# Incorrectly formatting of URLs containing an underscore

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fail of markdown parser detected if _ are used in naked url](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100882/fail-of-markdown-parser-detected-if-are-used-in-naked-url)
>   [YouTube URL parser chokes on underscore and dash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117689/youtube-url-parser-chokes-on-underscore-and-dash)

URLs containing an underscore which is not prefixed by an alphanumeric character are incorrectly parsed.

Examples:

```
1. http://_
2. http://youtu.be/_-validId     http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-validId
3. http://fop/#_cantbeinvalid_
```

Result:

1. http://_ <sup>A magical `">` at the beginning</sup>
2. [http://youtu.be/*-aValidId*](http://youtu.be/_-aValidId) <sup>and</sup> [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-validId](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-validId)
3. [http://foo/#*cantbeinvalid*](http://foo/#_cantbeinvalid_) <sup>Notice markdown at the end</sup>

Comment: This question was asked earlier today: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117689/youtube-url-parser-chokes-on-underscore-and-dash

Comment: Hmm, the auto-linker probably shouldn't even attempt to link the first example...

Comment: @TimStone - It also shouldn't attempt the last either, because it lacks a TLD, correct?

Comment: @KevinVermeer That'd probably make sense too, yeah. Checking for some sort of TLD would prevent `http://localhost/` from being auto-linked, which sounds reasonable.