# URL ending in underscore is incorrectly converted

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, url-encoding

If an URL posted in a question or answer body ends in an underscore, then this underscore is cut off from the URL, which produces a broken link when saving the text. At the same time the preview formats the link correctly.

Compare:

- Manually formatted link: https://dbfiddle.uk/RygDR_Y_
- Autoformatted link: https://dbfiddle.uk/RygDR_Y_

Try to edit this post - both links are correct in the preview.

Comment: Starts with an underscore too: [Incorrectly formatting of URLs containing an underscore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117778/282094)