# Markdown confused by odd-ball URL?

Tags: bug, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Link with double-underscored word in URL renders incorrectly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117230/link-with-double-underscored-word-in-url-renders-incorrectly)

I was trying to improve the appearance of SO question ['How to set OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameter to use byte instead of char'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799269/how-to-set-oraclecallablestatement-regist-to-use-byte-instead-of-char), and tried to convert the URL at the end into a clickable link.

The raw text for the URL is:

```
docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleCallableStatement.html#registerOutParameter_java_lang_String__int__int__int_
```

Note the double underscores in there.

When treated as plain text, you get:

> docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleCallableStatement.html#registerOutParameter_java_lang_String__int__int__int_

When prefixed with `http://`, you get:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleCallableStatement.html#registerOutParameter_java_lang_String__int__int__int_

(For the record, I see:

```
int_int_int">http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleCallableStatement.html#registerOutParameter_java_lang_String_int_int_int
```

with some portions in italic font (3rd 'int' in the prefix; first and third 'int' at the end.))

I think that is a bug in Markdown of some sort - albeit that the URL is very confusing.

Comment: @balpha: I agree it covers the same ground as the duplicate, but the problem persists two weeks after the previous bug report.  When is the problem actually going to be fixed?