# Bug in Markdown rendering: images having underline character in the image description

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

### Problem

This code,

> `![“Are you coming to bed? —I can’t. This is important. —What? —Someone is _wrong_ on the Internet.”](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXAfo.png)`

renders correctly in preview as an embedded image. But after posting it no longer renders correctly. Instead it renders as a text fragment:

> `wrong on the Internet.”">`

### Demonstration

Open the this post in the editor and see how the following code renders in the preview:

[image: “Are you coming to bed? —I can’t. This is important. —What? —Someone is _wrong_ on the Internet.”]

### Workaround

Avoid the underline character. This code renders correctly after posting:

> `![“Are you coming to bed? —I can’t. This is important. —What? —Someone is -wrong- on the Internet.”](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXAfo.png)`

### Discussion

I suppose underlines in the image description are mistaken for [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown). In the image description they really should be taken as literals (or at least ignored); regardless, they should not cause the sort of rendering error shown above.

Comment: I guess it's strongly related to [Link with double-underscored word in URL renders incorrectly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117230/link-with-double-underscored-word-in-url-renders-incorrectly) and [Fail of markdown parser detected if '_ 's are used in a naked URL](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100882/fail-of-markdown-parser-detected-if-s-are-used-in-a-naked-url) (the latter being status-declined).

Comment: As an aside: I wonder if formatting in alt-text is ever useful?

Comment: Given that the code renders properly in preview, just not after post, I would hope this is a very easy fix rather than one that would be declined.

Comment: @Arjan Sure. On any of the programming sites, a variable name with underscore separation could be part of an alt-text. But from the links you supplied, I understand that this bug also affects URLs themselves, not just alt-text: surely underscores in URLs should not be misrendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server-side Markdown version had two methods for creating image HTML, and only one of them handled this correctly. This version would have worked:

```
![“Are you coming to bed? —I can’t. This is important. —What? —Someone
is _wrong_ on the Internet.”][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXAfo.png
```

The JavaScript implementation already handled both versions correctly, since it already combined the handling of both versions into one single method that did the right thing.

From the next build on, the server-side implementation [does the same](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/source/detail?r=ec645b58c6d1be671396fa1caeba6aa7ea0f0a3b).